# PHP Fazer um POST em Página com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, post, libcurl

Uma Página *PHP*, precisa passar via `POST` alguns parâmetros para uma página externa, até ai OK, porém esta página externa possui alguns comandos *JavaScript*.

Quando eu envio via `cURL` ou `FileGetContent`, a página carrega, porém o *JavaScript* não é executado.

Tentei via *Ajax*, porém não funcionou devido a estrutura MVC do meu Projeto.

Alguém tem alguma dica de como chamar uma página externa via `POST` e fazer com que esta página execute o *JavaScript* inline dela?

Abaixo como estou chamando via **FileGetContent**

```
    $url = "http://localhost/workspace/application/files/origin/oitprintteste.php";

    $content = http_build_query($data);

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $content,
        )
    ));

      $teste = file_get_contents($url,true,$context);
```

Agora um Exemplo de como Chamo via **cURL**

```
    $url = "http://localhost/workspace/application/files/origin/oitprintteste.php";

    $content = http_build_query($data);

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $teste = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Tem como postar alguma linha de código pra análise da situação? Assim fica meio vago pra entender seu problema

Comment: Acabei de adicionar Samuel, Havia Esquecido...

Comment: Você quer fazer um request através do PHP em uma url (que serve um conteúdo html) e quer que o conteúdo js dessa página seja executado? É isso mesmo?

Comment: Isso mesmo @TomMelo

Comment: Então, isso não vai acontecer...O protocolo HTTP trabalha em cima de texto, requests e responses devolvem texto (body, headers e etc) seguindo as normas do protocolo. O responsável pela execução de um script js é o browser(existem outras formas mas esse é o cenário padrão). Portanto, no seu caso, fazendo um request através do backend(PHP) o script da página não será executado.

Comment: Entendido @TomMelo Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, realmente vou partir para outra estratégia. Obrigado